# I don't want to use @html.Action and @Rendersection can any one guide me what i use

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, c#-4.0

I don't want to use @html.Action and @Rendersection can any one guide me what i use

i have a menu there is lot of companies coming in `<li>` it is fetching from DB

the menu should show on every page and it fetch from Db.some one told me to create a Class

but i don'thave idea what he want to say

```
  public PartialViewResult FeaturedStoresMenu()
        {
            var model = _context.companyService.GetFeaturedStores();
            return PartialView(model);
        }
```

```
                            @RenderSection("FeaturedCategoriesMenu", false)
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Coupons</a>
                            <ul>
                                @Html.Action("FeaturedStoresMenu", "Home")
                            </ul>
                        </li>
```

yes on many pages but i don't want to use "RenderSection" and "html.Action" is there any other thing which i can use.....Because if i use @renderSection so i have to pass List from every controller to View to show my Companies....

Comment: Can you more elaborate your question? What I understand is that you want to use a menu on many pages???

Comment: yes on many pages but i don't want to use "RenderSection" and "html.Action" is there any other thing which i can use.....Because if i use @renderSection so i have to pass List from every controller to View to show my Companies.....@syed Salman

Comment: *Why* don't you want to use `Html.Action`? You can put this in your Layout and just use the same action every time, so you only need to pass the list from the controller in one place.

Answer (score 2):

you need to render the collection of your menu sub items in partial view.

Action

```
public PartialViewResult FeaturedStoresMenu()
    {
        var model = _context.companyService.GetFeaturedStores();
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

View = FeaturedStoresMenu (partial)

```
@model YourAppNamespace.YourModelType //type is collection for example List<SumenuItem>
<ul>
     @foreach(var item in Model)
     {
        <li ><a href="@item.SubmenuUrl">@item.SubmenuName</a></li>
     }  
</ul>
```

And if u need pass the parameter to your child action like this

```
@Html.Action("FeaturedStoresMenu", "Home", new {id = 555})
```

action should be

```
 public PartialViewResult FeaturedStoresMenu(long id)
    {
        var model = _context.companyService.GetFeaturedStores(id);
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

Or u can write custom Html helper method and write the menu logic in this method. example:

```
public static class LabelExtensions
 {
      public static string Label(this HtmlHelper helper, string target, string text)
      {
           return String.Format("<label for='{0}'>{1}</label>", target, text);

      }
 }
```

from [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)

Comment: yes on many pages but i don't want to use  "html.Action" is there any other thing which i can use..

Answer (score 0):

Make a PartialView which contains your menu, Put it in Views/Shared folder

then put it on any page where you want it like

```
@Html.Partial("NameofView")
```